# Can't resolve an Import in JavaCV

Tags: java, opencv, import, javacv

I've been trying to make a computer vision project using OpenCV/JavaCV and I want to store an image into a `Mat` variable using `imread`.

This is what I'm doing: `Mat img=imread("C:/Reference/to/Pic.jpg");`

It's no compiling since an import is not resolved, specifically this one.

`import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgcodecs.imread;` 
Its telling me that "The import org.bytedeco cannot be resolved".

All my other imports are seemingly working as intended. What's the problem here? Is this not the import for `imread`? Is there a problem with the installation of OpenCV/JavaCV?

Comment: What IDE are you using? did you include your library in the project?

Comment: @Emad, I'm using Eclipse and I think I've included all libraries, all other OpenCV specific functions do work it's just imread the refuses to cooperate.
Is there a certain jar that has to be included for "org.bytedeco"?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that OpenCV/JavaCV has some dependency which is not added to your project. `org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgcodecs.imread` is located in **javacpp-preset** repository which is github repo in https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets.

First of all, I suggest to read the **README.md** for javaCV repository carefully to findout how to import javaCV to your project. This was clearly explained in JavaCV README.md:

> Manual Installation
>
> Simply put all the desired JAR files (opencv*.jar, ffmpeg*.jar, etc.),
>   in addition to javacpp.jar and javacv.jar, somewhere in your class
>   path. Here are some more specific instructions for common cases:

Comment: I have those JAR files in my classpath.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read an image and store it into a Mat variable you can simply use [Highgui.imread()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread). I don't see why you want to use JavaCv when Opencv gives you all what you may need.

Comment: The Highgui module was discontinued, wasn't it? In current versions it'd be `Imgcodecs.imread()`.

It's just frustrating when things aren't working as they should.

Comment: Yup, i'm working with opencv 2.4.13 so it's Highgui.imread() for me. But from Opencv 3.0 release it becomes under Imgcodecs.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late.
I found this useful.In fact Javacv and org.byteco dependencies version are not compatible.So,In maven repository,If you want to  use Javacv dependency
You can find the compatible dependencies of org.bytedeco.op below listed as
Compile dependencies(x)
I hope,it can help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).